# Multiple selection checkbox list in WPF Data Grid Column

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to create DataGrid in which each row has column which allows user to select multiple hobbies(as shown in image).I dont know how to do this in wpf .I am new to wpf.Can anybody please help?

[image]

also i want to show one of the selected checkbox value in column.

Answer (score 2):

1- Install: `Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit -Version 3.4.0` (Or use NuGet in your project References).

2- Add it as Custom DataGridColumns:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    <!-- DO NOT FORGET TO ADD THIS -->
    xmlns:xwt="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"/>

<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column 1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xwt:CheckComboBox />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column 2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xwt:CheckComboBox />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

</Window>
```

[See the CheckComboBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/)